# PHPUnit + crontab: only header when output result to file

Tags: php, phpunit, output, cron

I want to run PHPUnit on prod server every hour and write result to file. Here's the crontab line:

```
0 * * * * cd /path/to/project && /usr/local/bin/phpunit --exclude-group acceptance > phpunit.result
```

When I run that command manually `phpunit.result` contains expected result, but when using crontab there's only the PHPUnit header in `phpunit.result`:

> PHPUnit 4.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Configuration read from /path/to/project/phpunit.xml

How can I achieve correct output PHPUnit result to file using crontab?

Comment: Looks like the process hangs. Can you verify this using `ps ax | grep php` ?

Comment: I think it stops right after start. When I run phpunit manually it take 3-4 minutes to complete all tests and I can see phpunit process. In case of crontab job I can't see that process at the right time.

Comment: What do you have in the cron log? If it is empty, you can try `strace -f` the cron process to see what happens when `phpunit` is started.

Comment: @user3584460 in cron log (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`) there's [expected output](http://pastebin.com/4SLYSpFM). `strace -f cron` isn't very helpful, here's the [output](http://pastebin.com/PtCPbAJA)

Comment: You are trying to start a new `cron` process and that would not work, as `cron` is already running. Try to attach to the existing process - `strace -fp cron_process_id` (I think I did not explain well in my previous comment and thought that `-p` option is implied).

Comment: @user3584460 thanks for clarification! Here's the [output](http://pastebin.com/R05P5xkT)

Comment: OK, not exactly what is needed (the trace contains only some info from `postfix`), but a step forward. You have to wait until you are sure that the `phpunit` job has passed. The output will be huge, so you can store it as a file by adding `-o dump.txt` option and upload the file somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use in with one command using full paths. Something like:

```
php /usr/local/bin/phpunit -c /path/to/project/phpunit.xml > /tmp/phpunit.log 2>&1
```

It will redirect the std error to the file, too. Then you will see what is actually happening when you run those tests.

Comment: Sorry for delay in my reply. Sir, you're the life saver! For some reason I have PHP Fatal error when running phpunit from crontab. But now I can see what happens and I can fix error. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use like this commends in Linux system...

1. sudo crontab -e  =>(create cron tab)

   -> learn command = */2 * * * * wget (i am created crontab for every 2 mins..)

   -> create command for crontab = */2 * * * * wget -q http://localhost/trigger_yoururl

   -> ^o run that..

   -> ^x exit that..
2. sudo crontab -l  =>(list view for cron tab)
3. sudo crontab -r  =>(remove cron tab)